# Missing right quote in callableStatement.getString result

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, single-quotes, callable-statement, java-stored-procedures

I am calling an Oracle stored procedure from spring boot application. The SP will return either Y or N (status). It is working perfectly in SQL Navigator. But when i call it from Java I am getting the status as "Y   (i.e. with an opening quote and no closing quote)

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter("isavailableflag", OracleTypes.CHAR);
String isUserExists = callableStatement.getString("isavailableflag");
```

isUserExists  = "Y

How to resolve this issue? For now, I am handling from Java but I am looking for a cleaner solution.

**Stored Procedure**

```
PROCEDURE isusernameavailable (applicationname IN VARCHAR2,
username IN VARCHAR2                                           
isavailableflag OUT CHAR)
.
.
.
```

Comment: Try changing **OracleTypes.CHAR** to **OracleTypes.VARCHAR**

Comment: Even after changing it to OracleTypes.VARCHAR, I didn't find any difference. Still getting "Y

Comment: Can you try String.valueOf(callableStatement.getString("isavailableflag").charAt(0))

Comment: It worked perfectly. If you provide your solution in answer, I will mark that as the correct answer and upvote it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the CHAR and convert it to String

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter("isavailableflag", OracleTypes.CHAR);
String isUserExists = String.valueOf(callableStatement.getString("isavailableflag").charAt(0));
```